# MS Visual Studio 2010 Professional Project Designer not appearing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, project, designer

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional and have been looking at how to change the icon of my program. One of the solutions suggested I go to the project's properties and in the project designer, click the app section and that I would be able to edit what the icon file is.

My problem is this: When I open the properties of a project, it gives me this 
[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1XPq.png)

From what I understand this is the property page. This is not what I'm looking for. I am told that the project designer looks something like this:

[Project Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLFuh.png)

How can I alter my project so that when I click the property setting, it allows me to open the project designer instead of this? Or, how else can I access the project designer?

Answer (score 0):

The first window you showed is the one we get for the properties of a c++ project. The second one we get it for the properties of a c# project. 
I have excactly the same problem as you. I need to change some compiler settings.